# Is there a NUMA-like mechanism for a DRAM?

Tags: linux, unix, memory, ram, numa

Can I create, for example, two buffers on adjacent memory chips? On chips that are physically closer to the CPU. Or is it implied that ram physical addresses are always adjacent in space? You could say that the physical location's impact on access latency is negligible, but I'm just curious.

Does Unix-like systems has such functionality?

Comment: That wouldn't be "NUMA-like", it would be NUMA.  But note that it's the arrangement of the connections to the memory (are there multiple memory controller channels?) that matters, and not whether chips are physically adjacent or physically close to the CPU.  Speed is determined by the interconnect circuitry.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Also, you'll need to be running on bare metal (rather than the usual virtual memory the OS runs your process in) or the OS must provide a mechanism to explicitly map specific physical blocks of memory into the address space of your process. The `mmap` syscall is normally used to map physical memory but I'm not aware of any OS that lets you choose the physical addresses.